# Set variable using osascript

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a Python script to get the volume level of my Mac as a variable that I can manipulate:  Pretty much exactly [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102552/get-the-current-volume-level-in-os-x-terminal-cli).  But when I try to run the same commands from my shell, I don't seem to be able to set the variable to a new value.

```
>>> ovol = "dummy"                                                                 
>>> call(['osascript', '-e', 'set ovol to output volume of (get volume settings)'])
88 #this is correct
0 #not sure where this comes from
>>> ovol
'dummy'
```

Comment: `88` is the standard output of `osascript`; 0 is the return value of `call`.

Comment: changing the volume on my mac changes 88 as expected

Comment: '''>>> call(['osascript', '-e', 'set ovol to output volume of (get volume settings)'])
25
0'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you would use [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

```
from subprocess import check_output
ovol = check_output(['osascript', '-e', 'get volume settings'])
print ovol
```

Now you'll just have to parse the string returned from 'get volume settings'.

Comment: Perfect!  For future readers for this exact use case, `ovol = check_output(['osascript', '-e', 'set ovol to output volume of (get volume settings)'])` works!